# WordPress Site has 35K spam images

Tags: spam

I am helping a client whose site has numerous plugins and 35K spam images from Zillow.  They are in the media library.  He also has 100K spam comments.  I have since then disabled the comments.  He also had over 300 users with no roles.

I have removed all users except the one with admin privileges.

How can I go about removing all pictures not uploaded by the admin?

I obviously cannot manually go through everyone, but I do not see a filter option for Author type.

Comment: That would have been easier before removing the users.

Comment: If you could find/know what images the client uploaded them self, then you could delete all of them and add those images back.

Comment: Expanding Gerald's comment: open the table `wp_posts` in the database and check if the columns `post_author`, `post_date` or `post_modified` can help locate this images.

Comment: Thanks brasfolio.  I can just query the table where post_author != "myusername".